# Port Type and Binding mandatory for WSDL?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

We received a WSDL from partner and it just have only wsdl:types, no port type and binding.
When it's imported in SOAP UI it throws error saying nothing to import. 
Is this a valid WSDL? how can i build a web service using this?

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<wsdl:types>
    <xs:schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <xs:element name="Trans">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="xxxName" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="xxxId" type="xs:integer"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="xxxId" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:simpleType name="xxxType">
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:minLength value="6"/>
                <xs:maxLength value="15"/>
                <xs:pattern value="[0-9]*"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>

    </xs:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="xxxInfo">
    <wsdl:part name="xxxPara" element="Trans"/>
</wsdl:message>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the catch with any XML you can create a right royal mess of things. So this appears to be part of WSDL. It is not a complete WSDL it is not valid and it is not going to be workable.

Contact your partner and ask them about it, this does not seem right maybe a corrupt file.

The port type and bindings are essential as they define a couples of important facts like how the XML is transported for example via HTTP/ SMTP (yes you can do soap over email) and what type of XML we are dealing with Document/RPC etc.

The fragment above is essentially a XSD with a sprinkling of WSDL tags. 
By No means is it workable.